# Запрос в MySQL DLE, как получить все ID существующих новостей

Tags: dle, mysql

Подскажите как получить из таблицы dle_post в массив список ID ТОЛЬКО существующих новостей на сайте

Пример как я получаю число всех постов на сайте :

```
//получаем кол-во новостей на сайте
$db->super_query( "SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM " . PREFIX . "_post WHERE id" );
```

их может быть к примеру 100, а ID занятый 100-й новостью может быть 150, так как новости постились и удалялись, а ID считает счетчик только в большую сторону.

Все что нужно это получить в массив все ID существующих новостей.

Comment: Что значит "существующих новостей" и зачем `where id` в запросе?

Comment: повторюсь, есть таблица dle_post в ней у каждого поста свой ID
к примеру 10 постов ID последнего 14, так как 4 новости уже удалили
вот мне нужно получить в массив список только существующих ID без ID удаленных (пустышек) к примеру ID существоующих будет 1,2,3,4,7,8,9,11 ... тут ID 5,6,10 проупущены так как поста с таким ID не существует

Comment: @Александр Internetov Если действительно, удалены, то Вы должны получить именно то, что Вы отметили: 1,2,3,4,7,8,9,11... 
Только в Ващем запросе, Вы получаете их количество, а не список.
Вы уверены, что записи в таблице dle_post физически удалены? Скорее всего, они помечены как удалённые. В таблицах CMS-систем, как правило присутствуют поля вроде "published"/"deleted".

Comment: Да посты физически уделены, привожу скрин http://clip2net.com/s/2FFUv
все верно в своем запросе я получаю только количество постов цифрой общей суммы
а мне нужно получить массив из ID всех существующих, исходя из скрина нужен запрос в чтобы в массив добавилось 1,2,3,4,14,15,16,17

Comment: @Александр Internetov @Ale_x Вам привёл ответ.

    SELECT id FROM ' . PREFIX . '_post WHERE 1

Comment: @Александр Internetov Странно, что Вы  выбрали проприетарную CMS DLE для погружения в web-ремесло. Хорошо, допустим, что для Вас это принципиально.
К сожалению, с API/ORM DLE я не знаком, накопать тоже не получилось. Буду руководствоваться вот этой статьёй:

[Создание простого модуля для CMS Datalife Engine][1]

  [1]: http://habrahabr.ru/post/130082/

Comment: @Александр Internetov, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

```
$sql = $db->query('SELECT id FROM ' . PREFIX . '_post WHERE 1');

while ($row = $db->get_row($sql))
{
  echo $row['id'] , '<br />';
}
```

Comment: Вот теперь то что нужно!
СПСИБО ОГРОМНОЕ!
Вот теперь как я понял если постов на сайте 100500
то и запросов будет 100500, правильно ли я понял ?

Comment: @Александр Internetov 
Нет, переменная $sql хранит объект с результатом запроса, а get_row парсит его в ассоциативный массив (аналог PDOStatement::fetch() или mysql_fetch_array())

Comment: Огромное вам человеческое спасибо !

Answer (score 0):

запрос

```
SELECT id FROM {PREFIX}_post
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$row = $db->super_query( "SELECT id FROM " . PREFIX  . "_post" );

var_dump($row);
```

выводит:

array(1) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" }

выводит всего 1 ID а как вывести все ID всех новостей ?